# How to set labels on xAxis inside Mpandroidchart line chart?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I'm trying to give label on xAxis inside mpandroidchart in line chart but get error every time.

Where did I go wrong?

Or should I follow another approach?

If I have to then what is it?

```
 public class OpdIpdAnalysis extends AppCompatActivity{

            ApiService service;
            TokenManager tokenManager;
            Call<ModelResponse> call;

            private ListView mListView;

             //GraphView
            private LineChart mLineChart;

             @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_opd_ipd_analysis);


                //GraphView casting
                mLineChart =(LineChart) findViewById(R.id.lineChart);
                mLineChart.setTouchEnabled(true);
                mLineChart.setPinchZoom(true);

                    //code for retrofit call

                    call = service.getAllOpdIpdData();
                    call.enqueue(new Callback<ModelResponse>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call<ModelResponse> call, Response<ModelResponse> response) {
                            myProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null) {
                                updatUI(response.body().getOpdIpdComparison());

                                List<Entry> entries1 = new ArrayList<>();
                                List<Entry> entries2 = new ArrayList<>();
                                //final List<String> xLabel = new ArrayList<>();

                                for (OpdIpdModel opdIpdModel : response.body().getOpdIpdComparison()){

                                    entries1.add(new Entry(opdIpdModel.getMonth(),opdIpdModel.getoPD()));
                                    entries2.add(new Entry(opdIpdModel.getMonth(), opdIpdModel.getiPD()));
                                    //xLabel.add(opdIpdModel.getMonthString());

                                    String[] xLabel = {opdIpdModel.getMonthString()};
                                    XAxis xAxis = mLineChart.getXAxis();
                                    xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
                                    xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
                                    xAxis.setGranularity(1);
                                    xAxis.setAxisMinimum(1);
                                    xAxis.setCenterAxisLabels(true);
                                    xAxis.setValueFormatter(new MyXAxisValueFormatter(xLabel));
                                }

                                LineDataSet lineDataSet1 = new LineDataSet(entries1, "OpdLine");
                                lineDataSet1.setDrawCircles(false);
                                lineDataSet1.setLineWidth(4f);
                                lineDataSet1.setMode(LineDataSet.Mode.CUBIC_BEZIER);
                                lineDataSet1.setColor(randomAndroidColor1);

                                LineDataSet lineDataSet2 = new LineDataSet(entries2, "IpdLine");
                                lineDataSet2.setDrawCircles(false);
                                lineDataSet2.setLineWidth(4f);
                                lineDataSet2.setMode(LineDataSet.Mode.CUBIC_BEZIER);
                                lineDataSet2.setColor(randomAndroidColor2);

                                //add the data
                                List<ILineDataSet> iLineDataSets = new ArrayList<>();
                                iLineDataSets.add(lineDataSet1);
                                iLineDataSets.add(lineDataSet2);

                                LineData lineData = new LineData(iLineDataSets);
                                mLineChart.setData(lineData);
                                mLineChart.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                mLineChart.animateXY(1500,1500);
                                mLineChart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(10);

                                //mLineChart.setXAxisRenderer(new CustomXAxisRenderer(mLineChart.getViewPortHandler(),mLineChart.getTransformer(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT)));

                                Description description = new Description();
                                description.setText("Growth rate per month");
                                description.setTextSize(12);
                                description.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                                mLineChart.setDescription(description);
                                mLineChart.invalidate();

                            }
                        }           
        }
```

My app is crashing every time.

And I'm getting an error:

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4; index=4

Now how can I resolve this problem and set the label as I'm expecting?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your size of entries1, entries2 and xValues is not same. You need to set break point on following line:

```
xAxis.setCenterAxisLabels(true);
```

At this point check if all the three lists are equal in size. After that you need to debug where the conflict is then handle the case by adding 0 value or empty string if there is something null you are getting. But the size of all the three arraylist should be same to work.

Comment: My all list values are equal, and when i'm debugging its showing the value correctly, but app is crashing with same error. Giving error at this line @Override public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) { return mValues[(int)value]; }

Comment: which version of library are you using? Because in my IndexAxisValueFormatter getFormattedValue has only one argument float value. I am using v3.1.0

Comment: My version is 3.0.3

Comment: I change value to: xAxis.setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter() {
                @Override
                public String getFormattedValue(float value) {
                    return xLabel.get((int) value);
                }
            }); but still getting error

Comment: upgrade your library version or if that is possible for you share your project i will debug that

Comment: I did this then it's work, but first label doesn't showing, when value is 0 then it's crash again : xAxis.setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter() {
                    @Override
                    public String getFormattedValue(float value) {

                        if (value>=0){
                            if (value<= xLabel.size() - 1){
                                return xLabel.get((int) value);
                            }
                            return "";
                        }
                        return "";
                    }
                });